# How to stop enforcing child classes to implement parent constructor

Tags: java, constructor, extends

Let's consider the following class :

```
public abstract class Parent{
    
    protected Parent(Object object){
        
        /* ... */
        
    }
    
}
```

And the following one :

```
public final class Child1 extends Parent{
    
    public Child1(Object object){
        
        super(object);
        
    }
    
}
```

Is there any common way to stop enforcing the implementation of a constructor calling `super(object)` in classes extending the Parent class, so the Parent constructor is always called?

I'm wondering because I will have a bunch of classes extending the Parent one and all of them are going to share the same constructor, with no fancy exception, so I would save time (not so much but I'm also just curious).

Comment: If there's only one constructor in the `Parent` class, that constructor *has* to be called via `super`. What's the problem you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Also, why is your parent constructor `protected`? It's an abstract class, so only subclasses can be instantiated, just keep that constructor a normal `public` constructor?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writting `public Child(Object object){ super(object); }` in every subclass of Parent.

Comment: 1. You will have to live with it. Apparently even lombok won't help you with this. 
2. Also if you have complicated class hierarchy for simple project maybe your design is messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child class *always* has to call one of its parents' constructors.

This is true even in the case of a no-arg constructor in the parent class:

```
class Parent {
  Parent() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  Child() {}
}
```

The compiler will insert a call into the child's constructor:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  Child() {
    super();
  }
}
```

If the `Parent` class' constructor(s) all require arguments, the compiler cannot assume that it can pass through a `Child` constructor parameter:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  Child(Object first, Object second) {
    super(???);  // Which of the parameters do you pass here?
  }
}
```

Even in the case of just one `Child` constructor parameter, the compiler cannot know whether you really want to pass that one parameter as-is, or if you really intend to pass some value derived from it (or even not):

```
  Child(Object first) {
    super(first);
  }

  Child(Object first) {
    super(first + "");
  }

  Child(Object first) {
    super("Hello world");
    first.doThing();
  }
```

Each of these (and many more) are equally valid choices.

The compiler doesn't know what you want, so you have to tell it, explicitly. Sorry, no way around it.